# PHP get value from array->value

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
function factuur_get_cardetails($form, &$form_state) {
        //dd('getting cardetails');
        $commands = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($form_state['values']['field_invoice_line_deukendokter']['und'] as $line) {
            if (count($line) > 1) {
                // car
                //dd($line);

                // veld uitlezen
                $kenteken = $line['field_invoice_carlicensenumber']['und'][0]['value'];
                //dd($kenteken);
                $url = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/opendata.rdw/VRTG.Open.Data/v1/KENT_VRTG_O_DAT?$filter=Kenteken%20eq%20%27'."$kenteken".'%27';
                $xml =  simplexml_load_file($url);
                foreach($xml->entry as $entry){
                    $properties = $entry->content->children('http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata');
                    $auto = $properties->properties->children('http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices');
                    dd($auto->Handelsbenaming[0]);
                    $model = 'field_invoice_line_deukendokter[und]['.$i.'][field_invoice_carmodel][und][0][value]';
                    $id = "input[name='".$model."']";
                    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke($id, 'val', array($auto->Handelsbenaming));
                }
            }
            $i+=1;
        }

        return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
    }
```

The problem is when its gives me back [Object object] in my textbox while using

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke($id, 'val', array($auto->Handelsbenaming));
```

Tho when i make a log using dd($auto) i get this

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Brandstofverbruikbuitenweg] => 3.20
    [Brandstofverbruikgecombineerd] => 3.60
    [Brandstofverbruikstad] => 4.30
    [Catalogusprijs] => 20916
    [Cilinderinhoud] => 1560
    [CO2uitstootgecombineerd] => 95
    [Datumaanvangtenaamstelling] => 2011-07-19T00:00:00
    [DatumeersteafgifteNederland] => 2011-07-19T00:00:00
    [Datumeerstetoelating] => 2011-07-19T00:00:00
    [Eerstekleur] => GRIJS
    [G3installatie] => N.v.t.
    [Handelsbenaming] => DS3
)
```

So it somehow doesn't give me the value in "Handelsbenaming" and i don't know why.
Does anyone have an idea?

When i make a log dd($auto->Handelsbenaming);
it gives me this

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => DS3
)
```

but in my textbox it says [Object object] instead of DS3

Comment: `$auto->Handelsbenaming[0]` not the same as `$auto->Handelsbenaming`

Comment: I know, thats only a dd (log file) to test what it gives back. Doesnt matter if i change it or not

Comment: yes, well, why don't you try to log `$auto->Handelsbenaming` and see what you get?

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object is not an array and you can't just auto convert it to array

Comment: Change `array($auto->Handelsbenaming)` to  `get_object_vars($auto->Handelsbenaming)`

Comment: @CrazySabbath cause it gives back the same, i gives back [0] => "something" but still shows me [Object object] in my Textbox

Comment: @Anthony It doesn't help, its not even giving me [Object object] now.

Comment: try `array((string)$auto->Handelsbenaming[0])`